# Angularjs function not working after first repeat on ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, array-splice

My problem is that function `remove(item,quantity)` is not working after the first **loop**.. The code shows that when the quantity is equal to `zero`, it will automatically `splice` on the **array**.

this is my code

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch on="$index % 3" >
        <div class="col col-33" ng-switch-when="0" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-30">
                    <img class="item_image"ng-src="http://WERBSITEISHERE.com/assets/uploads/itemImgs/{{items[$index].img_name}}" alt="" width="100%">
                    <div class="row menubtn-list nopadding">
                        <ul style="inline-block">
                            <li><button class="menubtn-add"ng-click="quantity = quantity+1;addorder(items[$index].item_name,items[$index].price,items[$index].description,quantity,items[$index].id)">+</button>
                            </li>
                            <li><span ng-show="quantity > 0">
                                 <button class="menubtn-minus" ng-click="quantity = quantity-1;addorder(items[$index].item_name,items[$index].price,items[$index].description,quantity,items[$index].id);remove(item,quantity)">-</button>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-70">
                    <span>{{items[$index].item_name}}</span><br>
                    <span>{{items[$index].description}}</span><br>
                    <span>&#8369; {{items[$index].price}}</span><br>
                    <input class="menu-quantity-txtbox" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="quantity" disabled>
                    <!--<div class="row">   
                        <button ng-if="quantity == 0"class="menu-order-btn">Order</button>
                        <button ng-if="quantity > 0"class="menu-order-btn"ng-click="addorder(items[$index].item_name,items[$index].price,items[$index].description,quantity,items[$index].id)">Order</button>
                    </div>-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-33" ng-switch-when="0">
            <span ng-show="items[$index+1]">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-30">
                    <img class="item_image" ng-src="http://WERBSITEISHERE.com/assets/uploads/itemImgs/{{items[$index+1].img_name}}" alt="" width="100%">
                        <div class="row menubtn-list nopadding">
                        <ul style="inline-block">
                            <li><button class="menubtn-add"ng-click="quantity = quantity+1;addorder(items[$index+1].item_name,items[$index+1].price,items[$index+1].description,quantity,items[$index+1].id)">+</button>
                            </li>
                            <li><span ng-show="quantity > 0">
                                 <button class="menubtn-minus" ng-click="quantity = quantity-1;addorder(items[$index+1].item_name,items[$index+1].price,items[$index+1].description,quantity,items[$index+1].id);remove(item,quantity)">-</button>
                                </span> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-70">
                    <span>{{items[$index+1].item_name}}</span><br>
                    <span>{{items[$index+1].description}}</span><br>
                    <span>&#8369; {{items[$index+1].price}}</span><br>
                    <input class="menu-quantity-txtbox" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="quantity" disabled>
                    <!--<div class="row">   
                        <button ng-if="quantity == 0"class="menu-order-btn">Order</button>
                        <button ng-if="quantity > 0" class="menu-order-btn" ng-click="addorder(items[$index+1].item_name,items[$index+1].price,items[$index+1].description,quantity,items[$index+1].id)">Order</button>
                    </div>-->

                </div>
            </div>
            <span>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-33" ng-switch-when="0">
            <span ng-show="items[$index+2]">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-30">
                    <img class="item_image" ng-src="http://WERBSITEISHERE.com/assets/uploads/itemImgs/{{items[$index+2].img_name}}" alt="" width="100%">
                    <div class="row menubtn-list nopadding">
                        <ul style="inline-block">
                            <li><button class="menubtn-add"ng-click="quantity = quantity+1;addorder(items[$index+2].item_name,items[$index+2].price,items[$index+2].description,quantity,items[$index+2].id)">+</button>
                            </li>
                            <li><span ng-show="quantity > 0">
                                 <button class="menubtn-minus" ng-click="quantity = quantity-1;addorder(items[$index+2].item_name,items[$index+2].price,items[$index+2].description,quantity,items[$index+2].id);remove(item,quantity)">-</button>
                                </span> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-70">
                    <span>{{items[$index+2].item_name}}</span><br>
                    <span>{{items[$index+2].description}}</span><br>
                    <span>&#8369; {{items[$index+2].price}}</span><br>
                    <input class="menu-quantity-txtbox" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="quantity" disabled>
                    <!--<div class="row">   
                        <button ng-if="quantity == 0"class="menu-order-btn">Order</button>
                        <button ng-if="quantity > 0" class="menu-order-btn" ng-click="addorder(items[$index+2].item_name,items[$index+2].price,items[$index+2].description,quantity,items[$index+2].id)">Order</button>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the function in the controller

```
 $scope.remove = function(item,quantity) { 
   //   console.log(item);
        if(quantity == 0){
            //$scope.orders = ordersService.getOrders();
            ordersService.getOrders().splice(this.$index, 1);  
        }
     // var index = $scope.orders.indexOf(item);
     //  ordersService.orders.splice(this.$index, 1);   
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the list without rules like "ng-switch-when='0'" to test the loop purely? Do the browser console warn you from something?

Comment: did you try `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"` in case there isnt any 'id' property in the item?